# what is equivalent function of Map.compute in scala.collection.mutable.Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Java has method in java.util.Map called `compute` which provides a way to update map when the key is present or absent in the map.

Does  scala.collection.mutable.Map provides any similar function?

I've checked the documentation [Map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html)  and [HashMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.html) but couldn't find equivalent ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `update` and `getOrElse` as in

```
val x= scala.collection.mutable.Map("a"->1,"b"->2)
x.update("c",x.getOrElse("c",1)+41)
x.update("a",x.getOrElse("a",1)+41)
```

Comment: Or perhaps `x("c") = x.getOrElse("c",1) + 41` which I think is clearer.

Comment: personally I think using mutable dataset is not clean (and a bad practice) to begin with

Comment: Java hashMap compute just get the value once, cost logN. But this of scala code get and update, cost 2 * logN

Comment: @yunfan - As I mentioned in the previous comment if you're using Scala you should use immutable collections anyway. Also, O complexity is important at scale there we'rent any reqs about that in the question

Comment: Is the above really atomic? The original question refers to `compute`, which guarantees atomicity. Here we have `x.update("v",x.getOrElse("c", 1))`, which is not obviously atomic.

Answer (score 2):

There is [`getOrElseUpdate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.html#getOrElseUpdate(key:K,op:=%3EV):V) defined in `mutable.MapLike` trait which does exactly what you want:

```
def getOrElseUpdate(key: K, op: ⇒ V): V
```

> If given key is already in this map, returns associated value.
>   Otherwise, computes value from given expression op, stores with key in map and returns that value.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer above can be simplified by configuring default value for the case when the key is absent. Also, read then update value can be done by one operator `map("key") += value`

```
val map = collection.mutable.Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2).withDefaultValue(1)
map("c") += 41
map("a") += 41

println(map)
```

returns Map(b -> 2, a -> 42, c -> 42)